# Enumerating binary sequences

Tags: c++, c, binary, sequence, counting

Suppose I wanted to enumerate all 4-bit patterns i.e. from `0 (0000) to 15 (1111)`. One way is the "truth table" approach:

```
0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, ... 1111
```

This approach is the equivalent of counting up from 0 to 15 in decimal.

Another approach would be using Gray codes, in which only one bit is flipped at a time:

```
0000, 0001, 0011, 0010, 0110, ... 1000
```

How would I systematically enumerate all numbers in an order that minimizes the sum of the bits? For example, something along the lines of:

```
0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 0011, 0101, 1001, 0110, 1010, 1001, 0111, 1011, 1101, 1110, 1111
```

for the 4-bit example.

Ultimately, it would be nice to extend this to any base, but the binary case seems the most straightforward to implement.

**EDIT:** I probably should have made it clear that the method must be generative i.e. I can't compute all the possible sequences and then sort them; the solution must iteratively produce the sequence in an order similar to the one specified.

Comment: This is more of a combinatoric question rather than programming.

Comment: This looks like a "combinations" problem.  For example, the set of numbers with 2 bits (out of 4) is the number of combinations of taking 2 items from 4.  The selected items are 1, the others are 0.  So just iterate c from 0 to n, and enumerate the ways of taking c items from n items.

Comment: You can pre-generate all the numbers representable in the chosen number of bits, sort them by bit count, and then present them one by one.  Or you can encode the algorithm that you used to generate the 4-bit variation by hand.  Is there a specific reason you want this?

Answer (score 2):

This bit-twiddling hack

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned u = x & -x;
  unsigned v = u + x;
  x = v  + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
  return x;
}
```

will allow you to easily enumerate all `unsigned` bit-combinations that contain the same number of 1-bits in increasing order. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system)

You can use this algorithm to sequentially enumerate all combinations with one 1-bit, two 1-bits, three 1-bits and so on. For example, for combinations up to 4 bits long (as in your example)

```
#define N 4u

int main()
{
  for (unsigned k = 1; k <= N; ++k)
  {
    for (unsigned subset = (1 << k) - 1; 
         subset < (1 << N); 
         subset = next_combination(subset))
      printf("%X ", subset);

    printf("\n");  
  }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c8327c5e0611eaa

The above Wikipedia link also contains a description of more general algorithm, not relying on any bit-twiddling.

Comment: This seems to work really well for binary sequences, but all this bit-twiddling leads me to believe that it would not generalize well to an arbitrary base. For example, my application requires a base of 256, so the "subset" in this example would really be an array of bytes, instead of an unsigned int. Are there ways of generalizing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{

    int n, p, j, i = 0, sum;
    cin >> n;

    bool *wsk = new bool[n];
    int hmany = static_cast<int> (pow(2, n));
    bool **sortarr = new bool *[hmany];
    for (int i = 0; i < hmany; i++) sortarr[i] = new bool[n];


    bool *wsk1 = wsk;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) *wsk++ = 0;
    wsk = wsk1;

    int z = 0;
    int c = n - 1;
    do
    {

        sum = 0;
        c = n - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (wsk[i] == 1) sum += static_cast<int>(pow(2,c));
            c--;

        }
        z = sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sortarr[z][i] = wsk[i];

        }

        z++; wsk = wsk1;
        i++; p = 0; j = i;

        while (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            j /= 2; p++;

        }

        if (p <= n) wsk[p] = ((1 - wsk[p]) != 0); 


    } while (p < n);
```

It is all what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This dumps a list of binary values, sorted by the count of set binary digits (population), ascending.  Numbers with equal populations are ranked according to ordinal value.

An array of `int` values is populated with every unique 4-bit integer.

std::sort sorts the array, using a lambda to compare values.  The lambda calls the function `population` to get a number's set bit count.

Then, the list is output by the function `dump_array` which converts integer values to `std::bitset` to get binary representations when sent to std::cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>


template <typename T>
int population(T x) {  // x<0 => oo loop
    int count = 0;
    while(x) {
        count += x & 1;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

template <typename A>
void dump_array(const A& a) {
    const char* delim = "";
    for(auto v : a) {
        std::bitset<4> bits(v);
        std::cout << delim << bits;
        delim = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 1<<4> vals;
    int i=0;
    for(auto& v : vals) { v = i++; }
    std::sort(vals.begin(), vals.end(), [](int a, int b) {
        const int pop_a = population(a);
        const int pop_b = population(b);
        return pop_a < pop_b || (pop_a == pop_b && a < b);
    });
    dump_array(vals);
}
```

Comment: I like that this method could conceivably be generalized to an arbitrary base (by modifying population), but I can't generate all the values ahead of time; the method must generate them one at a time in an order similar to the one I gave.

Comment: Yeah, AnT came up with a pretty good answer.  You could probably adapt it to arbitrary sizes using std::bitset

Comment: Yeah, but his answer involves bit-twiddling to get the next element in a binary sequence, so it won't generalize to an arbitrary base like I need.